# A message is not sent to an email via yandex in python

Tags: python, email, smtplib, yandex

I'm trying to run the python code, but it gives an error. He writes that the username or password is incorrect, but everything is correct. In the mail I made it so that insecure applications could use

My code:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

import smtplib

def send_email(to_addr,subject,text):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg["From"] = "email@yandex.ru"
    msg["To"] = "email@yandex.ru"
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text,"plain"))

    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.yandex.ru",465)
    server.ehlo("email@yandex.ru")
    server.login("email@yandex.ru","password")
    server.auth_plain()
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()


if __name__=="__main__":
    send_email("email@yandex.ru","Theme","Hi")
```

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\fedos\PycharmProjects\botmanagerui\sender.py", line 22, in 
send_email("email@yandex.ru","Theme","Hi")
File "C:\Users\fedos\PycharmProjects\botmanagerui\sender.py", line 15, in send_email
server.login("email@yandex.ru","password")
File "D:\Users\fedos\anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 750, in login
raise last_exception
File "D:\Users\fedos\anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 739, in login
(code, resp) = self.auth(
File "D:\Users\fedos\anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 662, in auth
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid user or password!            1682851755-FnItbCMDd8c0')

I tried to change the password, change the settings almost, but all to no avail